# Nginx rewrite /shop/anything to /shop

Tags: nginx, rewrite

We are using an embedded e-commerce store on our website, which works by adding the required JS script to the `/shop` page. On the server side, the requirement now is that all URLs of the scheme `/shop/anything` be rewritten to `/shop` for the server, because the rest of the part is meant to be processed by the embedded JS store.

I'm not able to write this and am getting `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/shop`. I think it's to do with regular expressions only, but I seem to be clueless.

My settings are as follows:

```
server {
    listen 8002 default_server;
    listen [::]:8002 default_server;

    location / { 
        root /home/mysite;
        rewrite ^/shop/.+$ /shop;
        index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
}
```

I've also tried `rewrite ^/shop/.*$ /shop;` but the result is the same. :|

Normally all the URLs are being processed by the `index.php` file at `/home/mysite` (which is actually the entry script for a framework), but I need the URLs after `/shop` not to be processed by the PHP framework but by the JS embedded on `/shop`.

What's the correct way to do this?

**== Update ==**

I happened to speak to one of the support developers from ECWID. While they don't have any Nginx examples, they were able to provide an Apache snippet. I hope it helps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~makfruit/shop/
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ .
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the script in `/shop` that processes the requests?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen That's hardly important in this case, but if you must know, please see https://support.ecwid.com/hc/en-us/articles/207359989-Product-Browser#GenerateCode. We are embedding the ECWID store on our `/shop` page.

Comment: That link doesn't appear relevant to the requirement to rewrite the URL.

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, it's not, but it's the answer to the comment by Tero above. The relevant section is here: https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#seo-friendly-urls

Comment: Yeah, that's the doc I expected to see, but it's kind of useless. You'd think they would have some proper examples already.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, they were able to provide me an Apache example. See my updated question if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work on the framework level. All I did was send any URLs matching `/shop/anything` to the same controller function that handles `/shop`. I'm not sure why the Nginx rewrite didn't work. I'm accepting this as an answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for the redirect cycle is that you are missing the `break` argument in your rewrite rule. So, your `rewrite` line should look like this:

```
rewrite ^/shop/.+$ /shop break;
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that there is no `index.php` at `/shop`. It's just a regular endpoint in the typical MVC pattern. The only entry script is placed at `/home/mysite/index.php`. When I checked the ECWID docs, their express statement was: rewrite everything `/shop/anything` to `/shop` and do not redirect. I'm sorry but I'm not clear how your example achieves that.

Comment: OK, I thought it was a regular front-controller pattern. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work as well. The redirection cycles are now gone, but I'm getting 404 for URLs of the type `/shop/anything`. An interesting side note: The store works perfectly (and was working without any Ngnix rewrites) if I navigate using the mouse only. I guess that's because it's the JS intercepting the URL and interpreting it. It's only when I visit that URL directly that I get 404, leading me to believe that the rewrite is not working as intended. :'(